# Alerts in Grafana are not triggerd

Tags: grafana

I have Grafana and I would like to add some alerts.
I added TestData as my input since it makes the development easier.
My problem is that my alert is not triggered and when it's triggered, it never switches to OK.

What am I missing? I did save the dashboard after every change.

For example why in this screenshot the alert is not triggerd?

[image]

Comment: How do you know that it's not triggered? Have you configured the notification channels?

Comment: I test it with TestRule and it's return false.